# php json encode parse error

Tags: php, json, pdo

This php file verify the id and code a user was emailed with. If the id and code match a confirmation message is shown else an error message is shown. The script is converted to json and the error returned occurs while parsing the json converted php.

Last but not least I create an empty array at the beginning of the php which I use to handle either the success or the error message and at the end that array named result is encoded to json.

this is the error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input`

```
<?php
require_once '../../dbconfig.php';

$result=[];

if(empty($_POST['verify_id']) && empty($_POST['code']))
{
 $result['success']=false;
 $result['error_msg']="empty codes";
}

if(isset($_POST['verify_id']) && isset($_POST['code']))
{
 $id = base64_decode($_POST['verify_id']);
 $code = $_POST['code'];

 $statusY = "Y";
 $statusN = "N";

 $stmt = $db_con->prepare("SELECT user_id,userStatus FROM tbl_users WHERE user_id=:uID AND tokenCode=:code LIMIT 1");
 $stmt->execute(array(":uID"=>$id,":code"=>$code));
 $row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 if($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
 {
  $result["success"]=true;
  if($row['userStatus']==$statusN)
  {
   $stmt = $db_con->prepare("UPDATE tbl_users SET userStatus=:status WHERE user_id=:uID");
   $stmt->bindparam(":status",$statusY);
   $stmt->bindparam(":uID",$id);
   $stmt->execute(); 
   $msg = "ok ";
    $result['success_msg']=$msg;
  }
  else
  {
     $result['success']=true;
   $msg = "active ";
    $result['success_msg']=$msg;
  }
 }
 else
 {
     $result['success']=false;
  $msg = "account not found ";
      $result['id']=$id;
    $result['error_msg']=$msg;  
 } 
}
echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

```js
/*get data to activate account*/
var verifyResult=[];
var success_msg=document.getElementById("container");

window.onload=function(){
 //sendDataToVerificationPage();
 var url = window.location.href;
    var myId = url.slice(77,79);
 var myCode= url.slice(87);
 sendDataToVerificationPage(myId,myCode);
};

/*send data to verification page*/
function sendDataToVerificationPage(myId,myCode){
   var oOutput = document.querySelectorAll("div"),
    oData = "verify_id="+myId+"&code="+myCode;
   var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
   oReq.open("POST", "verify.php", true);
   oReq.onload = function(){
    if(oReq.readyState==4 && oReq.status==200){
     receivedData(oReq);
    } else{
     oOutput.innerHTML = "error" + oReq.status + "occurred when trying to upload your file.<br\/>";
    }
   };
   oReq.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
   oReq.send(oData);
}

/*callback function to handle the received data*/
function receivedData(oReq){
    console.log(oReq.responseText)
 verifyResult=JSON.parse(oReq.responseText);
 console.log(verifyResult);
 if(!verifyResult.success){
  $("#container").fadeIn(1000, function(){      
  $("#container").html('<div class="alert alert-danger"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> &nbsp; '+verifyResult.error_msg+'</div>');
        });
 }else{
  success_msg.textContent=verifyResult.success_msg;
 }
}
```

Comment: It seems you have an error while decoding the JSON string. Can you show that part too? I assume it's javascript.

Comment: @Tchoupi do you mean I need to provide you with the js part too?

Comment: You need to parse your data before using it `JSON.parse(your_php_encoded_var)`

Comment: @AmrAly I have added the js part to provide you with further details as a user suggested me to do

Comment: Do you see the Ajax request / response in your browser developer toolbar? Does it look like valid json? It is possible that the php script fails for some unrelated reason, and doesn't return a valid json string.

Comment: @Tchoupi I've seen it and it is valid believe me I really can't find the error

Comment: try to remove all your `console.log` except the one after parsing your object

Comment: @AmrAly  I removed all the console logs except for that one after the parse

Comment: @Riccardo yes you right sorry about that.

Comment: @AmrAly don't worry man I've edited the question purposely and btw thank you for wasting your time trying to find an error I'm supposed to find

Comment: try to console log the data before parsing it and after to see the output

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141825/discussion-between-riccardo-and-amr-aly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed the problem by replacing the success and error message with plain text, as matter of fact I can't encode to json htlm tags in the way I tried

```html
$result['success']=true;
    $msg = "ok";
    $result['success_msg']=$msg;
    
    $result['success']=false;
    $msg="account already activated";
    $result['error_msg']=$msg;

    echo json_encode($result);
```